# Strong Markov Property for Brownian Motion in reverse time

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $(B_t)_{t\geq0}$ be a standard Brownian motion in $\mathbb{R}$ and let $T$ be a stopping time. Then the Strong Markov Property gives that $(B_{T+t}-B_T)_{t\geq0}$ is a standard Brownian motion independent of $\mathscr{F}_T$.

I am wondering if the same also holds for negative times: suppose that $T\geq1$ is a stopping time always greater or equal than $1$ (e.g. $T=\inf\{t\geq 1\,|\,B_t=0\}$), is it true that $(B_T-B_{T-t})_{t\in[0,1]}$ is a Brownian motion? The usual proof does not work since we must now work in a new filtration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Note that the stopping time $T$ can depend on all the values of $B_t$ with $t\le T$.  So you could take something like
$$T=\inf\{t\ge 1: B_t=0, B_{t-1/2}>0\}.$$
In this case $(B_T-B_{T-t})_{t\in [0,1]}$ cannot be a Brownian motion, since its value at $t=1/2$ is always negative.

Comment: Great answer. Do you know if in the particular case of $T=\inf\{t\geq1\,|\,B_t=0\}$ we still get a Brownian motion?

Comment: I now believe that the answer to my question is no because of Blumenthal's $0-1$ law: $X=(B_T-B_{T-t})_{t\in [0,1]}$ cannot be a Brownian motion because for each $\omega\in \{T>1\}$ (which is a set of positive measure), there exists an $\epsilon>0$ (depending on $\omega$) such that $X_t$ is not $0$ for all $t\in[0,\epsilon]$, while using Blumenthal's law it is easy to prove that a standard BM changes sign infinitely many times near the origin.